# What is the mechanical element that holds a worm gear shaft in place called?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears

Here is [an image of a worm gear](http://s.hswstatic.com/gif/gear-worm.jpg). What is english word for mechanical element (two of them will be necessary for a worm gear) in which the worm shaft will "lie" and rotate?

Here is one photo of the element where it is part of a housing; I need it as separate mountable element (I will mount it on plate):

[image: unknown element in worm gear housing]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Anything that holds a shaft and allows it to rotate is called a "bearing". It could be a simple metal bushing or a complete assembly with inner and outer races holding balls or rollers.

A bearing that is designed to be mounted to a surface is sometimes called a "[pillow block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pillow_block_bearing)".

Comment: +1  I have also heard "bearing block" occasionally.

Comment: Or 'mounted bearing,' more generically.

Answer (score 6):

Not only does the shaft have a "bearing" surface but the ends of the shaft also need something to "bear" against due to the "thrust" of the shaft in either direction.  So I would add the term "thrust bearing" to the mix some where in there ... this can be as simple as adding a single steel ball for a bearing surface to each end of the shaft to deal with the worm gear's lateral movement unless you have dealt with this in some other way.